# Magento 2 - How can I import / export categories from M2 to M2?

Tags: magento2, category, import, export

I'd like to import and export using two Magento 2, among two environments.
I know that I can't do it natively, so how can I do using MySQL or some free tool?

Comment: Magento does not provide such functionality. You can develop it by yourself or buy an extension.

Comment: In response to @leo s' answer: is it a migration to an identical setup? (like from staging to production or vice versa?) Or are it two different Magento 2 sites?

Comment: Use `setup:backup --db` and `setup:rollback --db-file="..."` command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing/exporting categories on the same Magento, which means both Magento has same EAV category attributes, you can use the native way to export SQL to the destination.
[image]

[image]

Using HeiSQL, use **export database** then tick all table with **catalog_category** prefix and export to your server database directly.