# create category and sub category programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, php

I need to create more then 50+ category. I Tried manually it take a too much of time so how to create category programatically?

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


function readCSV($csvFile){
 $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
 }
 fclose($file_handle);
 return $line_of_text;
}
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'csv/categories.csv';
$arrResult = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrResult);
echo '</pre>';

importCategories( $arrResult, $objectManager, $storeId );

/**
 * Import categories to Magento
 *
 * @param $arrResult
 */ 
function importCategories( $arrResults, $objectManager, $storeId )
{
    $parentId = '2';
    $list = array(); 
    foreach ( $arrResults as $import_category ) {        
        try {             
            $enabled = ( strtolower( $import_category[5] ) == 'true' ) ? 1 : 0;
            $parentId = ( $import_category[1] == 0 )? '2' : $list[$import_category[1]];     
            $url = strtolower($import_category[2]);
            $cleanurl = trim(preg_replace('/ +/', '', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', urldecode(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($url))))));
            $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
            /// Add a new sub category under root category

            $category = $categoryFactory->create();
            $category->setName(ucfirst($import_category[2]));
            $category->setIsActive( $enabled );
            $category->setUrlKey($cleanurl);
            $category->setData('description', strip_tags($import_category[10]));
            $category->setParentId($parentId);

            //$mediaAttribute = array ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
            //$category->setImage( $import_category[6], $mediaAttribute, true, false);// Path pub/meida/catalog/category/
            $category->setStoreId($storeId);
            $rootCat = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($parentId);
            $category->setPath($rootCat->getPath());echo"hi";
            $category->save();echo"hi";
            $list[$import_category[0]] = $category->getId();
            echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo 'Something failed for category ' . $import_category[2] . PHP_EOL;
            print_r($e);
        }
    }
    return $list;

}
```

Comment: Above code was read a categories file. But not creating category.it show  error....... wt can i do

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157767/magento-2-how-can-i-import-export-categories-from-m2-to-m2

Comment: @MahalakshmiM: Plz update your error.>!

Comment: @MahalakshmiM: Nenga direct database import panunnga.

Comment: It's was working..thank u....created category and sub category programmatically